# "The time of/into/in/by your watch"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

> What is the time *_* your watch?
>
> 1. of
> 2. into
> 3. in
> 4. by

Which preposition is correct?

Comment: *By*, because your watch is the means by which you discover the time.

Comment: Or *on* might be more common.

Comment: @RoaringFish thanks for clarification 
@neil@ I was also confused between **on** / **by** but i find **by** is more appropriate in this context.

Comment: @neil ~ I have never heard "what is the time on your watch?".

Comment: @Roaring Fish: I'm sure ***by*** is more common, but it's not that unusual to refer to the ["time **on** my watch"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood)

Answer (score 0):

The only two I've heard are

> *on your watch*

and

> *by your watch*.

Either one is fine and they both mean the same thing:

> **"What time does your watch {have / say (it is)}?"**

This seems to me a question to be asked when you think that your watch might be running fast or slow. If you just want to know what time it is, you can ask

> "Excuse me, but can you tell me what time it is?"

or

> "Excuse me, but do you know what time it is?"

Avoid asking **"Excuse me, but do you have the time?"** and no one will snap back with **"For what?"**